# Git Pre-Receive Hook Handle Git Rebase

Tags: git, githooks

I have a git pre-receive hiook and I was it to be able to determine if a push contains a rebase. I can't seem to find a definitive way to handle this online and wondering if anyone would have any suggestions?
I currently can handle merge requests no problem with the below code but doesn't handle a rebase.

```
parent_count=$(git rev-list --parents -n 1 "$rev" | awk '{print NF-1}')
if [[ $parent_count -gt 1 ]]; then
  exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Solution I found was to check the HEAD of the incoming commit to see if it is different to the current branch you are working on. It's not perfect but is currently working for my implementation.

```
  head_name=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
  branch_name=$(basename "$refname")
  if [[ $head_name != $branch_name ]]; then
    exit 0
  fi
```